# how to do to retrieve person.photos[0].default?

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried to retrieve the variable Default from json of people api but it doesn't work with "default" . how to do it ? thank you for your answer

see my test script below, please (last line at bottom)

```js
var person = People.People.get('people/' + accountId, {personFields: 'names,photos,phoneNumbers,addresses,birthdays,sipAddresses,organizations,genders'});
  //** var val_displayName_P = person.names[0].displayName;
   var val_photoUrl = person.photos[0].url.replace("=s100","=s128");
  var primary_BLN  = person.photos[0].metadata.primary;
  var default_BLN  = person.photos[0].default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is not returning `default` field in JSON response when a particular `accountID` contains user-provided photo(`default : false`), looks like a bug to me, not sure.

In case of User-provided photo, this is the log i am getting :-

[image]

And in case of default photo:-

[image]

Maybe that's why execution is breaking at last line.

If this is the case, for now you can try this :-

```
const photo= person.photos[0]
var default_BLN = photo.hasOwnProperty('default') ? photo.default :  false;
```

**Reference:**

[Photo](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#photo)

Comment: for ossian. Thank you for your answer.  Before to try this , I don't understand so well your explication . To try it,  I wonder if we should take all "var default_BLN = photo.hasOwnProperty('default') ? photo.default :  false; "?
if not only a part " var default_BLN = photo.hasOwnProperty('default') ? " ? .   could the url content be the same for "contact" and for "profile"?

Comment: for ossian , it works  !!!... thank you very much four your help

Answer (score 0):

JSON is case sensitive, try `person.photos[0].Default`.

Comment: thank you for your answser. But , this doesn't work too  !... How  to do ?...